# Symfony - FormType - Dynamic choices

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I've a Form with 1 EntityType field that must contain choices depending of a second EntityType field that is not mapped in the first entity, like this :

ServicePlaceType.php :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('placetype', EntityType::class, array(
            "class" => "AppBundle:PlaceType",
            "choice_label" => "place",
            "mapped" => false
        ))
        ->add('idplace', EntityType::class, array(
            "class" => "AppBundle:Place",
            "choice_label" => "place"
        ))
        ->add('...');
```

The tables

```
+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+
| Service | ServicePlace |     Place     | PlaceType |
+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+
|         | id           |               |           |
+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+
|         | idplace >    | < id          |           |
+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+
| id >    | < idservice  | idPlaceType > | < id      |
+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+
| service |              | place         | placetype |
+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+
```

So, when i select a PlaceType i want that the Place select shows only the places where idplacetype match the PlaceType id.

I tried in javascript, with an onChange event on the PlaceType select, that filter the Place options according to the PlaceType actual value, but i don't know how to fetch the PlaceType property of the Place in the formType.
I tried that kind of things, but it doesn't work

```
->add('idplace', EntityType::class, array(
            "class" => "AppBundle:Place",
            "choice_label" => "place",
            "attr" => array("placeType" => $this->getPlaceType()), // nor like that
  ))

  ->add('idplace', EntityType::class, array(
            "class" => "AppBundle:Place",
            "choice_label" => "place",
            "attr" => array("placeType" => function ($place) {
                return $place->getPlaceType();
            }), // neither like that
   ))
```

Does someone know how to fetch these datas ? Or how to dynamically filter options by another way ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: try wih 'choice_label' => 'placeType',

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I thought about that, but i need that the label be the place name !

Comment: did it work? :)

Comment: Juste see it now :x. The yceruto solution was the good one for me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [jquery](http://jquery.com/) library a little more simpler:

First, we change the builder a bit for render the place type id into `<option data-type="...">` using the `choice_attr` option:

```
$builder
    ->add('placetype', EntityType::class, array(
        "class" => "AppBundle:PlaceType",
        "mapped" => false
    ))
    ->add('idplace', EntityType::class, array(
        "class" => "AppBundle:Place",
        'choice_attr' => function ($place) {
            // output: <option data-type="...">...</option>
            return array('data-type' => $place->getPlaceType()->getId());
        },
    ))
```

Next, in you template:

```
{# ... #}

{{ form(form) }}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // when the 1st <select> was changed, then update the 2nd 
    // from current value and data-type option attribute.
    $(document).on('change', '#form_placetype', function () {
        var $idplace = $('#form_idplace'),
            // current value
            placetype = $(this).val(),
            // select available options from current value
            $available = $idplace.find('option[data-type="' + placetype + '"]');

        // deselect when the 1st <select> has changed.
        $idplace.val('');
        // hide no available options from current value
        $idplace.find('option').not($available).hide();
        // show available options from current value
        $available.show();
    });

    // Update 2nd <select> on page load.
    $('#form_placetype').trigger('change');
</script>
```

Comment: 'choice_attr' was the solution ! I wanna hug you right now :)