# Pass choicetype value from twig to js in symfony 5.4

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am using Symfony 5.4

How can I pass my choiceType value to js to change dynamically.

Controller

```
$languageForm = $this->createForm(SelectLanguageForm::class,$languageEntity,array('languagecode' => $formattedLanguageData));
```

where $formattedLanguageData is choiceType options in key value pair.
languageEntity is Entity class with get and set for languagecode eg :'en'.

This is the code in the form

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $languageChoices = $options['languagecode'];
        $builder
            ->add('languagecode', ChoiceType::class, ['choices' => $languageChoices,'label' => 'Select Language',
                ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'languagecode' => false,
        ]);
    }
```

and calling the form in twig as

```
<div class="language-dropdown" style="min-width: 90px;">
    {{ form(languageForm) }}
</div>
```

How can I pass the language code from the form to js to change it dynamically.

Comment: Check the generated HTML and write JS accordingly?

Comment: @DarkBee Can you show an example please or any documentation.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400337/symfony-formtype-dynamic-choices) for an example. We can't help if you don't dump your generated HTML. This is not a twig nor symfony problem